# How to #define strings the right way?

Tags: c, syntax, header-files, getcwd

I am recreating a basic bash like shell and I use `getcwd` for determining the path I am currently in to print it in a nice way.

I have this in my header file:

```
#define BLUE "\e[1;36m"
#define WHITE "\e[0;00m"
#define PWD getcwd((NULL), 0)
#define PROMPT BLUE PWD WHITE
```

Then, I try to print `PROMPT` using a putstr but when I compile I get this error:

```
cc -g3   -c -o src/minishell.o src/minishell.c
In file included from src/minishell.c:9:
src/minishell.c: In function ‘minishell’:
src/../include/minishell2.h:14:13: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘getcwd’
   14 | #define PWD getcwd((NULL), 0)
      |             ^~~~~~
src/../include/minishell2.h:15:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘PWD’
   15 | #define PROMPT BLUE PWD WHITE
      |                     ^~~
src/minishell.c:36:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘PROMPT’
   36 |     my_putstr(PROMPT);
      |               ^~~~~~
src/minishell.c:36:14: note: to match this ‘(’
   36 |     my_putstr(PROMPT);
      |              ^
make: *** [<builtin>: src/minishell.o] Error 1
```

I would love some help on how I can define a string and print it the same way I call any other string but use the color variables I have set with `BLUE` and `WHITE`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you expect `BLUE PWD WHITE` to concatenate the strings. That will not work. Adjacent string literals are concatenated during compilation; `"abc" "def"` will become `"abcdef"`. But `PWD` is not a string literal; it is `getcwd((NULL), 0)`. The `getcwd` routine returns a string at run-time. You cannot concatenate it that way. The easiest solution may be to write three separate calls to `my_putstr`, one for `BLUE`, one for `PWD`, and one for `WHITE`. Alternatively, you need to write additional code to concatenate strings.

Comment: I thought there would be a way to add them all together during the header file process but I guess I will go the route you have given, thanks!